# How do I create a globally-editable variable in Greasemonkey scripts?

Tags: javascript, variables, greasemonkey, information-retrieval

I need a code that creates a variable for every person using the Greasemonkey userscript.

So, if *Person1* edits the var `location = "Street"` to `location = "City"`, everyone using the script will see the change to "City".

Is there an easier way than using an external PHP/MySQL script, where the var is stored, fetched and can be edited?

Answer (score 0):

***If***, and only if, the users all use the same browser on the same user account, on the same machine, then you could use [`GM_setValue()`](http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_setValue) or [`localStorage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/dom/storage#localStorage) to contain the value.

But, for any other situation, you will have to have a central server application, that the script reads and writes the value to (using [`GM_xmlhttpRequest()`](http://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_xmlhttpRequest)).  There is no way around that; Greasemonkey has no mechanism for peer-to-peer communication.